# Counting the number of duplicates in a list

Tags: python, list, count, duplicates, sequence

I am trying to construct this function but I can't work out how to stop the function counting the same duplicate more than once. Can someone help me please?

```
def count_duplicates(seq): 

    '''takes as argument a sequence and
    returns the number of duplicate elements'''

    fir = 0
    sec = 1
    count = 0
    while fir < len(seq):
        while sec < len(seq):
            if seq[fir] == seq[sec]:
                count = count + 1
            sec = sec + 1
        fir = fir + 1
        sec = fir + 1
    return count
```

In: `count_duplicates([-1,2,4,2,0,4,4])`

Out: `4`

It fails here because the output should be `3`.

Comment: How do you even define "number of duplicate elements"? Number 2 is there twice and number 4 is there three times. Are you counting the number of occurrences of the most frequent element?

Comment: Have you tried using a `Counter` yet?

Comment: @AlexTaylor and zvone There's one duplicated 2 and two duplicated 4s, making a total of 3.

Comment: @zvone if the same value appears more than once in a sequence, I'm calling all copies of it except the first: duplicates.

Comment: So if you pass `count_duplicates` a `seq` of `[1,1,1,1]`, it'll return 3+2+1=6. You can fix that by only counting the 1st dupe for each item, by putting `break` after the `count = count + 1` line. But it'd be better to use one of the more efficient techniques.

Comment: So, in `[-1,2,4,2,0,4,4]`, the duplicates are 2, 4 and 4, which is a total of 3 duplicates? If so, the solution is `len(seq)-len(set(seq))`

Answer (score 7):

You can just create a `set` from your list that would automatically remove the duplicates and then calculate the difference of the lengths of the created set and the original list. 
Like so:

```
def count_duplicates(seq): 

    '''takes as argument a sequence and
    returns the number of duplicate elements'''

    return len(seq) - len(set(seq))

res = count_duplicates([-1,2,4,2,0,4,4])
print(res)  # -> 3
```

If you are not allowed or don't want to use any built-in shortcuts (for whatever reason), you can take the long(er) way around:

```
def count_duplicates2(seq): 

    '''takes as argument a sequence and
    returns the number of duplicate elements'''

    counter = 0
    seen = set()
    for elm in seq:
        if elm in seen:
            counter += 1
        else:
            seen.add(elm)
    return counter

res = count_duplicates2([-1,2,4,2,0,4,4])
print(res)  # -> 3
```

---

Finally, as far as your code is concerned, the problems with it are outlined very nicely by @AlanB in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52090695/6162307). I chose not to bother correcting your code because in my mind this is an [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). It is obvious that you have some kind of programming background but your convoluted `while` loops is just *not the way things are done in Python*.

Comment: That works but you know how to do it without using 'set'?

Comment: @Cassy I updated my solution. Have a look.

Comment: @downvoter Can I have some feedback on what it is that could be improved?

Comment: I upvoted already, but maybe explain why Cassy's code gives the wrong answer. And I'll delete my comment on the question.

Comment: BTW, your alternative still uses a set. ;) Cassy probably hasn't been taught sets yet, so she can't use them for this assignment.

Comment: @PM2Ring My interpretation of the *do not use a `set`* requirement was *do not use a `set` to automatically remove the duplicates*. In the last code snippet, one can easily replace the `set` with a `list` or a `dict` or whatever mutable container one preferes.

Comment: Fair enough. A list would be ok, since the amount of dupes is likely to be small. And my guess is that she hasn't learned dicts yet...

Answer (score 1):

The solution of Ev. Kounis is the simplest and what you should use in my humble opinion. However, if you want to stick to your code, here is why it doesn't work:

With your intricate `while` loops you basically say "for every item in my list, increment `count` when you find a duplicate", which is basically what you want. But since you have two "4 duplicates", it increments `count` an extra time.

```
seq=[-1,2,4,2,0,4,4]
fir = 0
sec = 0
count = 0
print "Pairs of duplicates: "
for fir, item1 in enumerate(seq):
    for sec, item2 in enumerate(seq):
        if fir < sec and seq[fir] == seq[sec] :
            count+=1
            print(fir, sec)
    
print "Number of duplicates: ", count
```

Which outputs :

```
Pairs of duplicates: 
(1, 3)
(2, 5)
(2, 6)
(5, 6)
Number of duplicates:  4
```

The `(5,6)` pair is incorrect.

To fix this, simply add a condition to your `if` statement that prevents an item to be compared twice:

```
seq=[-1,2,4,2,0,4,4]
fir = 0
sec = 0
count = 0
duplicates=[]
print "Pairs of duplicates: "
for fir, item1 in enumerate(seq):
    for sec, item2 in enumerate(seq):
        if fir < sec and seq[fir] == seq[sec] and seq[fir] not in duplicates:
            count+=1
            print(fir, sec)

    duplicates.append(seq[fir])

print "Number of duplicates: ", count
```

Which outputs the desired result:

```
Pairs of duplicates: 
(1, 3)
(2, 5)
(2, 6)
Number of duplicates:  3
```

But again, doing

```
len(seq)-len(set(seq))
```

is a lot simpler and works just as well.

## EDIT:

I realized I didn't use while loops in my example.

```
def count_duplicates(seq): 

    fir = 0
    sec = 0
    count = 0
    duplicates=[]
    print "Pairs of duplicates: "
    while fir < len(seq):
        while sec < len(seq):
            if fir < sec and seq[fir] == seq[sec] and seq[fir] not in duplicates:
                count += 1
                print(fir, sec)
            sec += 1
        duplicates.append(seq[fir])
        fir += 1
        sec = 0
    return count 


c=count_duplicates([-1,2,4,2,0,4,4])
print "Number of duplicates: ", c
```

Comment: Yes, your mod to Cassy's code looks ok (I'm on my phone, so it's not easy to test it). But my suggestion to bail out of the inner loop as soon as the 1st dupe's detected is a little simpler & more efficient. ;) BTW, you can give `enumerate` a `start` arg if you don't want to start counting at zero. You *could* use that in the inner loop, but of course you'd also need to loop over a slice of `seq`.

Comment: I agree with you, I just wanted to keep the solution as simple as possible. Should I edit my answer?

Comment: Simple is good. :) My guess is that Cassy won't be able to use `enumerate`, and even your other solution may be getting a bit too advanced at this stage of her Python education. So feel free to add another version if it's simpler.

Comment: FWIW, I upvoted this answer because it explains why the OP's code gives the wrong answer, and shows a way to modify that code to get the correct count. Sure, there are better ways to do this task, but IMHO it's also very useful to get feedback like that, especially when you're still learning how to program.

Comment: I ran into this problem in my first attempt

Answer (score 0):

Approach using Pandas. This Approach is suitable for large list(s) with duplicates.

```
data = [-1,2,4,2,0,4,4]
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'data':data}) #Loading the data as Data Frame
print(df[df1==False]) #Printing Non-Duplicated Values
   data
0    -1
1     2
2     4
4     0
print(df[df1==False].count()) #Taking count of Non-Duplicate Values
data    4
dtype: int64
```